# Пример из Spring4. Spring+Hibernate. org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Реализую пример из книги "Spring 4 для профессионалов" из главы "Использование Hibernate  в Spring". Использую БД H2.
Вот моя структура: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое файла конфигурации (app-context-annotation.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/sql/schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/sql/test-date.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="icho"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:packagesToScan="icho"
          p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties"/>

    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </util:properties>

</beans>
```

Собственно сам класс реализующий интерфейс DAO

```
package icho;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.List;

@Transactional
@Repository("contactDao")
public class ContactDaoImpl implements ContactDao {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ContactDaoImpl.class);
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Contact> findAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from icho.Contact c");
        List<Contact> list = (List<Contact>) query.list();

        return list;
    }

    public List<Contact> findAllWithDetail() {
        return null;
    }

    public Contact findById(Long id) {
        return null;
    }

    public Contact save(Contact contact) {
        return null;
    }

    public void delete(Contact contact) {

    }
}
```

Содержимое pom.xml (здесь может быть много чего лишнего)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.dinislam</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernatesample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Собственно как я все это запускаю

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.load("classpath:META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml");
        context.refresh();

        ContactDao contactDao = context.getBean("contactDao", ContactDao.class);

        listContacts(contactDao.findAll());

    }
```

Получаю такую вот ошибку

```
"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=59197:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\JavaProjects\SpringInAction\hibernatesample\target\classes;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.1.5.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.1.6.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.3.11.Final\hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.3.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging-annotations\1.2.0.Beta1\jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\4.0.5.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\1.1.0.Final\jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.3.11.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar;C:\Users\Dinislam\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.197\h2-1.4.197.jar" SpringHibernateSample
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory initDatabase
INFO: Creating embedded database 'dataSource'
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [META-INF/sql/schema.sql]
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
INFO: Executed SQL script from class path resource [META-INF/sql/schema.sql] in 31 ms.
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [META-INF/sql/test-date.sql]
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
INFO: Executed SQL script from class path resource [META-INF/sql/test-date.sql] in 32 ms.
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:34 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:35 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
ноя 13, 2018 10:32:35 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at SpringHibernateSample.main(SpringHibernateSample.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property telNumber in class icho.ContactTelDetail
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getSetter(Property.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertySetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:416)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
    ... 43 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: А в примере из книги говориться что надо давать методы доступа для переменных класса?

Comment: Да, если вы про class ContactDaoImpl, он выглядит так как и должен

Answer (score 0):

Пример абсолютно правильный. У данный книжки есть примеры в электронном варианте (см. http://www.williamspublishing.com/). Код не работал из-за наличия орфографических ошибок, наличии букв кириллицей вместо латиницы.